# Spring security with different type of sessions

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm using spring security 3.1.4 and I have the following problem. In one web app I have 2 types of users with different custom "UserDetails" instance. How do I differentiate between the users in the implementation of UserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername. Can I have 2 UserDetailsServiceImpl and know when to use each one?

Comment: "2 types of users" - what is the distinctive characteristic of those users? How can you tell them apart?

Comment: One is an admin user and the other is regular user. each will have a separate DB that saves there details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I suggest you to implement **composite** `UserDetailsService` and perform `loadUserByUsername` to both DB one by one. And it is logical, that the first `UserDetailsServiceImpl` to use should be for `regular user`, as soon as it is tipical, that the count of `admin user` is definitely less.

However by design it looks bad. It would be better to have separate **hidden** application for admins and get rid of a little vulnerability when simple user might guess an admin account.

Comment: Hi, thanks we decided to separate the two to different web apps